# Ember snapshot belongsTo always return null

Tags: ember.js

I have a relationship between two models as A has many B and B belongs to A. When loading A, B is sideloaded and I can use the inverse relationship B->A just fine in the template. However, when I try to use `belongsTo()` on a snapshot for one of the loaded B models, it returns null. Is that supposed to work and how come it works in the template but not with a snapshot in the adapter?

The code is as simple as the example here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/relationships/

As said above, it works fine in the template, but not with a snapshot in the adapter. I can also see in the debugger that `inverseRecord` is `null` on the relationship when stepping through the code for `belongsTo()`

EDIT:

Created a twiddle with an example of this. Check the adapter for `server` and the log output when pressing delete: https://ember-twiddle.com/71c98929c307284c78dae336d6cd040b. Expected is to be able to resolve the `belongsTo` relationship in the adapter but as seen it returns `null`. It can also be seen that it works fine in the template.

Comment: I tried doing something with serializer but serializes is clearly not the issue if it works in template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing relationship before deleting record. By calling `user.get('servers').removeObject(server)` relationship is deleted. Afterwards you are calling `server.deleteRecord()` which triggers your adapters `deleteRecord` method. Since relationship is deleted before `snapshot.belongsTo('user')` returns `null`. Just remove `servers.removeObject(server);` call to see expected behavior.